# Products not updating after Magento e-commerce upgrade

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I keep getting this error after upgrades,

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION' in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\helper\gallery.phtml on line 111

I have searched for solutions, but not working.

I have checked for this path "app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper", but it doesn't exist and the file is not there but i found this path "app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper", and the file "image.php, exists here?

I have renamed the image.php in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper to image.php.bak but where do i revert or move and paste the image.php to, since this path "app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper" doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you post your template code? Which version of Magento have you upgraded to? That constant is in class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` in 1.9.4.1, so you'd need to reference it as `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I upgraded to 1.9.4.2, i can see the class in "image.php", which is located on this path " app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper, but i don't know how to reference it.  
`class Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const XML_NODE_PRODUCT_BASE_IMAGE_WIDTH = 'catalog/product_image/base_width';
    const XML_NODE_PRODUCT_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH = 'catalog/product_image/small_width';`